# Using a variable which has been changed in an if statement

Tags: android, if-statement

I built two activities and the MainActivity is passing some variables to the activity "Calculation". This works as intended and the variables are submitted and received correctly. I now want to create the integer "size_int" depending on the values of the intent "size". The problem occurs in this line:

```
    debug1.setText(size_int);
```

Eclipse tells me that I should create a local variable with the name "size_int". I do not understand why "size_int" can not be used in this line because it has been defined in the if statement before. Do you have any ideas on that? I assume it has something to do that the variable "size_int" is being defined in the if statement but I am not sure.

Here is the full code:

```
package com.example.eggtimer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calculation extends Activity {



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculation);


        // get Intents (Size, Temperature and yolk from Main Activity)
        String size = getIntent().getExtras().getString("size");
        String temperature = getIntent().getExtras().getString("temperature");
        String yolk = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yolk");

        if (size.equals("Small")) {
            int size_int = 30;
        }



        // Debug Variables
        TextView debug1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDebug1);


        debug1.setText(size_int);

    }



}
```

Comment: Please read about Variable Scope section) :) It fails because you declared size_int in if statement.. what if you will get false? what will be then in debug1.setText(size_int)? I think it would be null btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change like below. This is because if you declare inside the braces, the scope is restricted, so you need to increase scope by declaring outside

```
int size_int = 0; 
if (size.equals("Small")) {
            size_int = 30;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, that's the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about concept called "variable scope". In general, variable **declared** in code block is **local** to that code block and is NOT visible outside. Therefore you should declare your `size_int` **outside** your `if()`:

```
    int size_int = 0;
    if (size.equals("Small")) {
        size_int = 30;
    }
```

In general, variables declared outside code blocks are visible in the blocks, while variables declared inside code block are local to that code block.